# Marshal model in different ways using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jaxb

Sure, this question was asked before anywhere but didn't find a appropriate solution for it:

Is there a possibility to marshal a model with JAXB to different XMLs or in different ways. I still serialize this model to JSON with Jackson where I can use @JsonView or [JsonMixins](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) to serialize it to different json layouts.

Having this model:

```
public class Customer {
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    private int id;

    public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }
    private String firstName;
}
```

should be marshalled as:

```
<customer>
    <lastName>name</lastName>
<customer>
```

or

```
<customer>
    <id>name</id>
    <lastName>name</lastName>
    <firstName>firstname</firstName>
<customer>
```

I found [this](/questions/9404105/marshalling-the-same-object-in-two-different-ways-using-standard-jaxb) and [this](/questions/9419732/using-jaxb-to-support-schemas-with-minor-variations/9432435#9432435) posting on stackoverflow but the suggestion is to use EclipseLink JAXB. But unfortunately Hibernate as a persistence provider is still in use. EclipseLink and Hibernate (both are O/R mapper) won't really work together - isn't it?

Is there any possibilty to marshal a model to different xml using JAXB?

Comment: You could marshall everything and then use xslt to filter the output.

Answer (score 0):

> I found this and this posting on stackoverflow but the suggestion is
>   to use EclipseLink JAXB. But unfortunately Hibernate as a persistence
>   provider is still in use. EclipseLink and Hibernate (both are O/R
>   mapper) won't really work together - isn't it?

EclipseLink provides JPA (O/R) and MOXy (O/X (JAXB) & O/J).  You can use the EclipseLink O/X with Hibernate O/R without issue.

With [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) you can use the Object Graph feature to output subsets of your model to XML or JSON.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-inputoutput-partial.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-partial-models-on.html

Comment: Thanks for your links! But when trying your examples with maven I got an javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: eclipselink.object-graph value: contact info; I imported lib like [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy/2.5.1); Additionaly imported javax.xml.bind.jaxb-api